# Regular expression accepts partial match

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex

I have some validation code that checks a string against a regular expression.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(RegexPattern);
if (!regex.IsMatch(value))
{
    errorMessage = "The data is not in the correct format.";
    return false;
}
```

If I set the regular expression pattern to `^[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*$`, it correctly accepts `1.0.0.0`; however, it also accepts `1.0.0.`.

How can I modify the pattern so that `1.0.0.0` is accepted but `1.0.0.` is rejected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[0-9]*` means 0 or more occurrence of `[0-9]`

`[0-9]+` means 1 or more occurrence of `[0-9]`

```
^[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*$
```

Change `*` to `+`:

```
^[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+$
```

Comment: Yup, that's what I was missing. Thanks.

Comment: This happens, the thing that you have done 100+ times. you do a simple and stupid mistake and the funny part is that you don't find it. I do it a lot ;). Glad could help.

Comment: Is this supposed to match `1234567`

Comment: @sln nope. because there must be for numbers separated by 3 dots

Comment: `^[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+$` matches `1234567`

Answer (score 2):

Just a slight misunderstanding about * and +. The former accepts either no occurrences or more (>=0), the latter only matches if such vocabulary occurs at least once (>=1).

```
^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$
```

I usually also escape the dot for safety, not entirely sure if it's necessary but I still do it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$
```

Explanation:

```
 ^ - begin of string
   \d - any digit
   + - at least one char
   \. - exactly a dot char
 $ - end of string
```

By the way, your input looks like an IP address. If so you can modify your reges like this:

```
^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$
```

{1,3} means: 'from 1 to 3 chars'

**Demo:** [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pPsjpE/2/)

Answer (score 0):

To match 4 sets of digits separated by a period

`^\d+(?:\.\d+){3}$`